# Hiding footer from multiple subpages in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to hide footer from multiple subpages but when i use

```js
{ window.location.pathname !== "/subpage1" &&<footer /> }
{ window.location.pathname !== "/subpage2" &&<footer /> }
```

It does not work but when using just one of these its works how to fix it ?

Comment: Can't you combine both to one ? something like { ((window.location.pathname !== "/subpage1") || (window.location.pathname !== "/subpage2" ))  ? <footer />  : null}

Comment: your code does not work but we could try maybe different suntaxe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it the same way as you tried to do, you can do it something like this. It would be the same idea for window.location.path . Replace "val" with "window.location.path" variables. I think i had extra curved braces in my comment.

https://codesandbox.io/s/64j3y7mlv3

```
 return (
    <div>
      <Comp1 />
      <Comp2 />
      <Comp3 />
      {val[0] === 1 || val[1] === 2 ? <Footer /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

For your case, it would be :

```
{ window.location.pathname === "/subpage1" || window.location.pathname === "/subpage2" ? null : <footer /> }
```

As I mentioned, I just gave you the basic idea. Its just about the conditional statement.

Comment: I do not understand where should i put my subpage1 and subpage2 in your syntax ?